# Redirect all pages except a few

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect all pages to a new domain page, except a few pages that have a custom new link on a new domain too.

I succeded to redirect ALL PAGES of `www.olddomain.com` to `www.newdomain.com`

Now I need, for example, to redirect:

- `www.olddomain.com/contacts` -> `www.newdomain.com/contact-us`
- `www.olddomain.com/who-we-are` -> `www.newdomain.com/our-story`

and more.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Since there apparently is no imediate way to somehow compute the new paths from the old references you will need to code them one by one, I am afraid:

```
RewriteEngine on

# do _not_ rewrite requests to newdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.newdomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ - [END]

# specific rewrite rules from olddomain
RewriteRule ^/?contacts$    https://www.newdomain.com/contact-us [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?who-we-are$  https://www.newdomain.com/our-story [R=301]
# ...

# redirect some paths to newdomain but keep the path
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/some-valid-path$ [OR]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/another-valid-path$  
# ...
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$  https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301]

# a general catch-all rewrite rule for all other old references
RewriteRule ^  https://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

These rules will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

---

Another approach would be to have a general rewriting rule targeting a script of yours which has some form of map from old to new reference. That lifts the redirection logic from the level of the http server to some scripting engine, php for example. That adds a lot of flexibility and sometimes ease, but will slow down the server.